# convert asynchronous process in synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm playing with javascript and node.js, so I was trying naively to make an asynchronous call synchronous (I know fs lib has readFileSync, this is just for playing)

So here's the code, it does a loop until the callback changes the flag value, and the loop should break and the flow should continue, but it hangs...

```
var fs = require("fs");

//read a file, just something asynchronous
var readfilesync = function(filename){

  var getout  = false,
      result  = null,
      error   = null;

  fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      error = err;
    }
    else {
      result = data;
    }
    getout = true;
  });
  while (!getout) {
    console.log('---waiting');
  }
  return (error)? error : result;
};

console.log("========== redis.conf: ",
    readfilesync("/var/log/system.log"));
```

Can anybody help me on a lecture about this ?
regards.

Comment: alright @FelixKling I understand that is blocking, can you help with further details ? any comprehensive article that could help me to get it better.

Comment: The loop and the callback are both run on the same thread. This means only one of them can run at a given time. So long as the while loop is iterating, the callback will never have an opportunity to fire, since the thread is completely occupied or "blocked" with the loop.

Answer (score 3):

`while (!getout)` is blocking, so the callback of `fs.readFile` never executes and `getout` never changes.

Remember, JS is single threaded. The callback can only be executed if resources are available, but they never become available because the `while` loop never terminates.

Maybe this helps to understand the execution model of JavaScript better: [MDN - EventLoop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop).